# How to detect file upload complete event in JSF2.0 using Ajax

Tags: jsf-2

Hope you all will be fine. Actually i want to upload image files from system to database. But i want that when user upload files then file didn't go to database directly but after selecting files .Files may save to some temporery location, so when user click on save button then i move all the images to database. I am using JSF 2.0 and PrimeFaces. I found code on someone blog. What code does is that after uploading files , it converted it to byte[] array.  I save that byte Array in a list so on save button i get images from the List.

Here is the code

```
private StreamedContent image;

public StreamedContent getImage() {
    return image;
}

public void setImage(StreamedContent image) {
    this.image = image;
}

public String imageUpload(FileUploadEvent event) {

    try {

        // Convert file from input stream to bytes
        byte[] byteArray = InputStreamToByte(event.getFile().getInputstream());

        /**
         * Add images to list so we can retrieve them when user click on save button
         */
        boolean add = images.add(new Images(byteArray));


        /**
         * Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
           String url = "jdbc:postgresql://x.x.x.x:5432/MYDB";
           Connection oConnection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, "username", "password");
           System.out.println("Sucessfully connected to Postgres Database");
         *
         * byte[] bytes = bos.toByteArray();
           String sql = "INSERT INTO my_table (byte_array) VALUES (?)";
           statement = oConnection.prepareStatement(sql);
           statement.setBytes(1, bytes);
           statement.executeUpdate();
           System.out.println("Image inserted into database!");
         */

        //byteArray used to store picture into database
        InputStream ist = new ByteArrayInputStream(byteArray);

        /*
         * StreamedContent Object used to show the picture in jsf pages. We need to convert
         * again bytearray to InputStream
         */
        image = new DefaultStreamedContent(ist, "image/jpg");

        FacesMessage msg = new FacesMessage("Succesful picture is uploaded.");
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, msg);

        //we dont need to use faces-config to navigate in jsf 2
        return null ;

     } catch (Exception e) {

         FacesMessage msg = new FacesMessage("Exception happen");
         FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, msg);

         e.printStackTrace();

         return null;

     }

} //end of imageUpload()
```

Here is my .html file

```
<h:panelGrid width="30%" columns="3">

    <h:outputText value="Map to upload" />
    <p:fileUpload id="uploadFile"
                  description="Image"
                  update="messages"
                  allowTypes="*.jpg;*.png;*.gif;*.jpeg;"
                  auto="true"
                  fileUploadListener=#{cityDetail.imageUpload} >

        <f:ajax event="????" execute="???" render="uploadedInage" />

    </p:fileUpload>

    <p:graphicImage id="uploadedImage"
                    value="#{cityDetail.image}"


</h:panelGrid>
```

Now i want that when image is completely uploaded, the image is also shown to the panel grid 3rd column. For this i am trying to use Ajax. But i don't know what event should i use. So please can any one tell me the event name and also i want to ask for execute i should use "@this" ? .Also tell me that is my approach is right that to save binary image in a List so that when user click on save button then i retreive all the images and send them to database. Also using Ajax is right idea here for my purpose?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *so when user click on save button then i move all the images to database*

Then just implement that accordingly?

```
<p:commandButton value="save" action="#{cityDetail.save}" />
```

with

```
public void save() {
    // Move all images to database.
}
```

Comment: Hi thanks, But what about the Ajax part. How can i detect file upload complete event ?

Comment: Hmm you mean to say there is no need to use 'code'<f:ajax event="????" execute="???" render="uploadedInage" />'code' . Also i have done the file upload part with actionListener. Is it better or there is no need to use actionListener? I have done in the following manner [code]<h:commandButton id="save" value="Save" actionListener="#{cityDetail.sendImagesToDatabase}" action="#{cityDetail.save}" style="position: absolute; top: 230px; left: 90px;" styleClass="ButtonStyle" />[/code] Thanks

Comment: This is not working [code] <h:outputText value="*" /> <h:outputText value="Map: " /> <p:fileUpload id="cityMap" description="Image" update="messages" allowTypes="*.jpg;*.png;*.gif;*.jpeg;" auto="true" fileUploadListener="#{cityDetail.imageUpload}" > </p:fileUpload> <p:graphicImage id="image" value="#{cityDetail.image}" width="140" />[/code] Is there any trick that when <p:fileUpload /> complete then <p:graphicImage /> run? Thanks

Comment: Oh, this way, use the `update` attribute of `<p:fileUpload>` like you already used for messages.

Comment: This is not working [code] <p:fileUpload id="cityMap" description="Image" update="messages image" allowTypes="*.jpg;*.png;*.gif;*.jpeg;" auto="true" fileUploadListener="#{cityDetail.imageUpload}" > </p:fileUpload> <p:graphicImage id="image" value="#{cityDetail.image}" width="140" height="100" /> What i am doing wrong ? Thanks

Comment: Did the browser retrieve a HTTP 200 or 304 response on the refreshed image? If 304, then it just means that it was been loaded from browser cache instead.

Comment: Hmm When i use the above code then there is just image with a cancel sign in it... i think it's a default cancel image for p:graphics. Anyways how can i check the HTTP 200 or 304 response on refreshed image? I just write the code in the NetBeans and then run the code. Thanks

Comment: Hi i solved my isseu by making ImagePath. Insted of getting image i use code like this                                             [code]<p:graphicImage id="mapImage"
                      value="#{cityDetail.imagePath}"
                      width="80" height="50" cache="false" />  [/code]                                                              Then in the bean i use code like this                         [code]private String imagePath = "/resources/images/Untitled.jpg";
      private String imagePath1 = "/resources/images" + "/"; [/code] Then i made path using image clicked Thanks